# How to read a local text file to a local html and read the content to a two dimensional array for javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to read a local text file to a local html and read the content to a array for javascript?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('myfile').onchange = readFile;
};
function readFile() {
    file = this.files[0];
    var fReader = new FileReader();           
    fReader.onload = function (event) {
        document.getElementById('fileContent').value = event.target.result;
    };
    fReader.readAsText(file);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> <input id="myfile"  type="file"     /></p>
    <textarea  id="fileContent" cols="68" rows="10"  ></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

It can read text file and print on the html.

But how to convert to an array in javascript?

The array in javascript I want is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var dataset = [
        [0,619804,7,128],
        [1,638224,6327,128],
        [2,639157,12342,64],
        [1,639157,6440,64],
        [3,645597,173,21],
        [4,645597,150,21],
        [5,645597,301,22],
        [6,645747,12153,17],
        [7,645898,15367,47],
        [8,646393,7650,22],
        [9,646393,321,21],
        [10,646393,18049,21],]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I guess your text file is in this form:

```
8,646393,7650,22
9,646393,321,21
10,646393,18049,21
...
```

So you just have to split with \r\n to transform into an array.

```
var resultText = event.target.result;
var array = resultText.split('\r\n');
```

And i have a array like this :

```
[
  "8,646393,7650,22",
  "9,646393,321,21",
  "10,646393,18049,21"
]
```

So if you want to transform this to you'r array type you just have to :

```
var newArray = [];    
for (var i = 0, max = array.length; i < max; i++) {
   newArray.push([array[i]])
}
```

And you should have this :

```
[
  [
    "8,646393,7650,22"
  ],
  [
    "9,646393,321,21"
  ],
  [
    "10,646393,18049,21"
  ]
]
```